# TFS2010 import TFS2008 sharepoint sites and content

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm testing a TFS 2010 install. I have the server set up and TFS 2010 installed. I have imported the projects from the existing TFS2008 server by doing backup's and loading them into the new sql server and then doing the import, which allworks fine.

How ever how do i get the Sharepoint site moved to the new server.

Environment is a single server install with TFS, SQL and sharepoint running on the same box. this is the same for 2008 and 2010.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you wanted to do your migration this way.  The TFS 2010 installation wizard includes an upgrade path, which should take care of all aspects of the upgrade for you.

Comment: i appreciate that, the problem is multiple teams that don't all want to move together, so i need to leave the server intact. the problem with the upgrade route is that it is a desstructive process